# How to arrange values of Object with uniqueID

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an object with details - name, email, contact with unique ID

```
{
 email_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "xyz@gmail.com"
 email_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "abc@gmail.com"
 mobile_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "223"
 mobile_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "122"
 name_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "mp"
 name_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "pp"
}
```

for example: `name_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662` this contains name_UniqueID but remains same for one set of form for name, email, mobile. These values are taken from as many forms generated in the frontend, form has unique Id and that has been pass to their fields, so how can I make a new collection of objects containing a name, email, mobile for a particular unique id as given.

```
example:

[
{
 id: "IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy"
 name: "mp",
 email: "",
 mobile_no: "",
},
{
 id: "QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662"
 name: "pp",
 email: "",
 mobile_no: "",
},
]
```

Comment: If you're storing those fields in any database like `Mongodb` then it'll automatically creates `unique` _id for each document. you want to do it with Purely JS?

Comment: @VishalSharma I'm not using any database I'm using nanoID to generate uniqueID

Comment: @prashantpadadune If you're already using `nanoID` then, what issue you're facing? DO you want to add those random IDs into those document fields in JS?

Comment: @VishalSharma i'm getting a single object for all the forms fields, i want to arrange those fields data inside the Unique ID which is generated via nanoID, see in my example my object is like name_unique for a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const input= {
      email_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "xyz@gmail.com",
      email_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "abc@gmail.com",
      mobile_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "223",
      mobile_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "122",
      name_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "mp",
      name_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "pp"
 }

const output=[];

for(let key in input||{}){

     if(key.startsWith('name_')){
        const id =key.replace('name_','');
        const obj={
             id,
             name:input[key], 
             email:input[`email_${id}`],
             mobile:input[`mobile_${id}`]
        };
        output.push(obj);
     }
}
console.log('output json', output)
```

Comment: This is correct but I want to assign values of `input` to the `obj` you created

Comment: key is assigned correct only the values are set with keys again

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem statement

Comment: with the example of the input and output?

Comment: Are you expecting the variable input should be array of objects instead of object at the end?

Comment: I got it, your solution is right but instead of `a` it should be input input[key].

Comment: Yes, i failed to update the variable name in obj variable. thanks, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it:

```js
const d = {
 email_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "xyz@gmail.com",
 email_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "abc@gmail.com",
 mobile_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "223",
 mobile_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "122",
 name_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "mp",
 name_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "pp"
};

const result = Object.values(
  Object.entries(d).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    const [field, id] = k.split("_", 2);
    if (!acc[id]) acc[id] = {id};
    acc[id][field] = v;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dependecies called `UUID` or `NanoId` from NPM. this dependencies can be used for an unique ID.
to apply it use:

```
const idVar = uuidv4() || nanoid();
const obj = {
 ['id_' + idVar]: 'abcdefg2312',
 ['name_' + idVar]: "pp",
 ['email_' + idVar]: "",
 ['mobileNo_' + idVar]: "",
}
```

Comment: I'm using nanoId to generate uniqueID, I'm trying to arrange name, email, mobile under that unique id

Comment: You dont know how to apply NanoId to the object? it simple, use NanoID method on the object properties example: `{
 id: nanoid(), 
 name: "pp",
 email: "",
 mobile_no: "",
}`

Comment: nanoId is applied properly there is no issue with nanoId, I want to arrange email, name, mobile under the uniqueID as given in example

Comment: Array on key object can manipulate variable

Comment: I got the solution above :)))

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but could be a sol:

```
const parentObj = {
         email_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "xyz@gmail.com",
         email_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "abc@gmail.com",
         mobile_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "223",
         mobile_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "122",
         name_IcWDC6iyNzsQe9sPss4Yy: "mp",
         name_QVXeOX1vijCtpx8mdD662: "pp"
    };
let resultArr = [];
for (const key in parentObj) {
    const template = {
        id:"",
        name:"",
        email:"",
        mobile:"",
    };
    let [prop,uid] = key.split("_");
    if(!resultArr[uid]){
        template.id = uid;
        resultArr[uid] = template;
    }
    resultArr[uid][prop] = parentObj[key];
}
console.log(resultArr);
```